# Why isn't my feature getting pushed to the features array?

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects, geojson

I'm trying to get data into geoJSON format but struggling with pushing my feature object to the features array. My console.log prints each object exactly how I would expect and I get an empty features array returned.

```
   const getGeoJSON = async () => {
    const devices = await getDevices()
    const devicesArr = devices.data.data.results;
     for (var i = 0, l = devicesArr.length; i < l; i++) {
      const deviceID = devicesArr[i].id;
      //console.log(deviceID)
      const cellObj = await writeCellStr(deviceID)
      const battObj = await writeBattery(deviceID)
      const connectObj = await writeConnecttime(deviceID)
      const feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [cellObj.long, cellObj.lat]}, "properties": {"name": cellObj.deviceName, "id": cellObj.deviceID, "url": cellObj.deviceURL, "cellstr": cellObj.cellstrValue, "cellstr_time": cellObj.cellstrTime, "battery": battObj.batteryValue, "batteryTime": battObj.batteryTime, "timeConnected": connectObj.connectValue, "connectTimeStamp": connectObj.connectTime}}
      console.log(cellObj,battObj,connectObj)
      features.push(feature);
      console.log(features)
    }
   return features
  } 


  getGeoJSON()
```

Comment: What makes you think feature is not getting pushed?

Comment: Please try adding a console.log after `features.push` to see what `features` looks like after each push.

Comment: Where have you define the `features` array?

Comment: Ah sorry. I had that console.log in there and that is where I saw nothing was in it. All undefined. I added it back.

Comment: @DevThiman I had it declared both in the function and outside neither seemed to work.

Comment: `console.log(devices)`, do you get devices properly after API call? and also value for `console.log(cellObj,battObj,connectObj`) for this?

Comment: I do. Here are the results of the console.log(cellObj,battObj,connectObj)

{}
cellstrTime: 1650967215616
cellstrValue: 50.51
deviceID: "61f2024c1d8472403be5a"
deviceName: "Boron"
deviceURL: "https://industrial.api.ubidots.com/api/v2.0/devices/61f207"
lat: 39.9182295
long: -79.8128526
[[Prototype]]: Object
 
{}
batteryTime: 1651021201000
batteryValue: 65
[[Prototype]]: Object
 
{}
connectTime: 1651021201000
connectValue: 11
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: @jjhi11 I tried declaring features[] inside the function and it seems work. I used basic async fetch() to get data since i don't have access to your api calls.